# Triggered C# method with various processing time

Tags: c#, multithreading, real-time

I have a c# method which is called periodically by a camera. The call event is known to be very precise. The camera is running at 2500Hz so this method should be called every 400 micro seconds.
Here is the simplified version of the method:

```
// Main class
private static List<double> T_Copy = new List<double>();
private static List<double> T_Call = new List<double>();
private static Stopwatch SW_Copy = new Stopwatch();
private static Stopwatch SW_Call = new Stopwatch();

void PeriodicalCalled()
{
    // (...) some other stuff inside a "if" condition which is not called for the sake of this test
    
    if (MyDLL.Flag)
    {
        // Elapsed time between method calls
        SW_Call.Stop();
        T_Call.Add(SW_Call.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        SW_Call.Restart();

        // Elapsed time to perform a copy
        SW_Copy.Restart();
        Buffer = new byte[4, 2560 * 3];
        SDK.GetBuffer(Buffer);
        MyDLL.CopyBuffer(Buffer);
        SW_Copy.Stop();
        T_Copy.Add(SW_Copy.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
    
    // This Flag is set once CopyBuffer has reached the end of its buffer size
    if (!MyDLL.Flag && T_Call.Count > 0)
    {
        string[] SaveText = new string[T_Call.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < T_Call.Count; ++i) SaveText[i] = "Call; " + T_Call[i] + "; Copy; " + T_Copy[i];
        File.WriteAllLines("timeTest.txt", SaveText);
        T_Call.Clear();
        T_Copy.Clear();
    }
}

// Enables test
void SetFlag()
{
    MyDLL.Flag = true;
}

// MyDLL class
public static bool MyFlag = false;
private const int SIZE = 20000;
private static byte[][,] MyBuffer = new byte[SIZE][,];
private static int MyBufferIndex = 0;

public static void CopyBuffer(byte[,] Buffer)
{
    MyBuffer[MyBufferIndex] = Buffer;
    MyBufferIndex++;

    if (MyBufferIndex >= SIZE)
    {
        MyFlag = false;
        // Do work with filled MyBuffer
    }
}
```

The test is triggered by calling the SetFlag() method. On each event triggered by the SDK, I create a new empty byte[,] array which will be populated by the SDK.GetBuffer() method. Then I send the array to MyDLL which will reference this array at the next index of MyBuffer.

So as you can see, each iteration of this code does exactly the same work.
However, when taking a look inside the timeTest.txt file, the time taken for each iteration is not the same.

Say, 19900/20000 iterations are correct (T_Copy values are lower than 50 micro seconds and T_Call values are close to 400 micro secondes (+- 5 micro seconds)).

The remaining 100 iterations really take much more time, up to 10 milliseconds and are randomly distributed among the 20000 iterations. Whenever this is happening, PeriodicalCalled() is blocking until the buffer copy is completed and in the next iteration T_Call will contain a value slightly higher than 10 milliseconds.

> Call  0,4432   Copy   0,0199
>
> Call  0,3823   Copy   12,3993
>
> Call  12,506   Copy   0,0094
>
> Call   0,3878   Copy   0,0069
>
> Call  0,3698   Copy   0,0069

- This code runs on a seperate thread with Priority.Highest
- I looked at the memory/cpu usage and everything seems fine.
- I deactivated several Windows services (Defender, Firewall, Update) but didn't change anything.

Do you have any idea why the performance suddenly changes ?

Thanks,

**Edit:**

Thanks to @germi for finding the origin of the problem. I modified the following  code:

```
// Enables test
void SetFlag()
{
    GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(SIZE * 4 * 2560 * 3);
    MyDLL.Flag = true;
}

public static void CopyBuffer(byte[,] Buffer)
{
    MyBuffer[MyBufferIndex] = Buffer;
    MyBufferIndex++;

    if (MyBufferIndex >= SIZE)
    {
        MyFlag = false;
        GC.EndNoGCRegion();
        // Do work with filled MyBuffer
    }
}
```

The only limit this imposes is that the maximum SIZE is around 8000 frames, which still represents around 250MB of memory.

Comment: My first guess would be the GC. Have you diagnosed whether the GC is running when you see these spikes? Using [`ArayPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=netcore-3.1) might help you.

Comment: `new byte[4, 2560 * 3]`.  That doesn't go on forever, sooner or later the garbage collector has to run.  Consider reusing the same array repeatedly to reduce (not eliminate) the overhead.

Comment: Why are you stopping and starting the stop watch?  I would just read the stop watch without stopping?

Comment: You're adding values to a list. Which is only a wrapper around an array. Once the array behind it is full it'll create a new array 2* the size of the previous one and copy all values of the first array over and add the new value that didn't fit. This is the reason list addition can sometime take up a lot of time. You could pass a large start size to the lists so there is no need for the intermediate copies.

Comment: And as said previously. GarbageCollector can also screw things from time to time

Comment: @germi: I'm checking in that direction right away !
@ Hans Passant: I c'ant reuse the same array, my final MyBuffer will point to the same array for each iteration ! The data in each iteration is different.
@ jdweng: That wouldn't change much, stopwatches are implemented only for testing.
@ Knoop: I agree with you, however, that would mean that there would be some kind of pattern when time would exceed. Besides, creating a new array would not take 10 ms or would it ?

Comment: fyi windows is not a realtime operating system.